# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise - Blank XAML App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I'm currently trying to learn C# from Head First C# (that's probably how is it called in english) book. In requires from me, that I use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. Then I have the option: Visual C# -> Windows Store -> Blank App (XAML). But when I run my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (college student here) - well I just don't have that option. Is there an equivalent option or something like that? Or should I just install another version?

Comment: I'd suggest getting a more up to date book...

Comment: 2014 is not so old, you know

Comment: You have a 2014 book that talks about VS2012 and not even VS2013? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Select `File => New Project => Visual c# => Windows => Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)`

Comment: @Frynio Don't forget to upvote (if you have enough rep) and accept answers that help you.

Comment: Rep is missing. I did, but